# Sublime is "touching" files from back-directory

Tags: node.js, file, sublimetext3

When I update a file on sublime in any folder, it touch all files in back directory with same basename of this directory when `atomic_save` is active. For instance, if I have:

```
/default/file.txt
/default.txt
/default.css
/file.txt
```

If I edit `/default/file.txt`, Sublime will touch too `/default.txt` and `/default.css`, but not `/file.txt`.

**Why it happen?** I'm using `chokidor` with node and it is get a lot of file changes, when I only save one file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not is the best answer. But I cached the initial `fs.Stat` of each watched file, and when it is "touched" I compare the `mtime`. For this case specific it works to me ([possibly an issue on `chokidar`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/253)).